# Saving NSUserDefaults with UISwitch in Swift 2

Tags: nsuserdefaults, swift2, uiswitch

I have posted all my code below to fully demonstrate what I am trying to accomplish. I have a UI Switch, that I would like to save a NSUserDefault on what game mode they would like. I am not sure why this is not working correctly, as it currently does not save- as the switch doesn't work.

```
import SpriteKit

class ModeScene: SKScene {

    var modeSwitch = UISwitch()
    var motionLabel = UILabel()
    var touchLabel = UILabel()

    override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {
        let MotionMode = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
        let TouchMode = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()

        modeSwitch.center = CGPoint(x: view.center.x, y: view.frame.size.height / 1.3)
        modeSwitch.addTarget(self, action: Selector("updateMode"), forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.ValueChanged)
        if TouchMode {
            modeSwitch.on = false
        }
        else{
            modeSwitch.on = true
        }
        self.view?.addSubview(modeSwitch)

        motionLabel = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 700, height: 200))
        motionLabel.center = CGPoint(x: view.center.x * 3.4, y: view.frame.size.height / 1.3)
        motionLabel.text = "Accelerometer"
        motionLabel.textColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
        motionLabel.font = UIFont(name:"ArialRoundedMTBold", size: 16)
        self.view?.addSubview(motionLabel)

        touchLabel = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 700, height: 200))
        touchLabel.center = CGPoint(x: view.center.x * 2.25, y: view.frame.size.height / 1.3)
        touchLabel.text = "Touch To Move"
        touchLabel.textColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
        touchLabel.font = UIFont(name:"ArialRoundedMTBold", size: 16)
        self.view?.addSubview(touchLabel)

        DoneBtn = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 400, height: 30))
        DoneBtn.center = CGPoint(x: view.center.x * 1.7, y: view.frame.size.height / 14)
        DoneBtn.setTitle("Done", forState: UIControlState.Normal)
        DoneBtn.setTitleColor(UIColor.whiteColor(), forState: UIControlState.Normal)
        DoneBtn.addTarget(self, action: Selector("done"), forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
        self.view?.addSubview(DoneBtn)

        updateMode()

    }

    func updateMode(){
        if modeSwitch.on {
            // mode is accel
            let MotionMode = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
            MotionMode.setValue(true, forKey: "MotionMode")
            NSLog("Mode is accel")

        }
        else{
            // mode is touch
            let TouchMode = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
            TouchMode.setObject(true, forKey: "TouchMode")
            NSLog("Mode is touch")
        }
    }

    func done(){
        self.scene?.view?.presentScene(StartScene(size: self.scene!.size), transition: SKTransition.fadeWithColor(UIColor.blackColor(), duration: 1))
        headerLabel.removeFromSuperview()
        DoneBtn.removeFromSuperview()
        modeSwitch.removeFromSuperview()
        touchLabel.removeFromSuperview()
        motionLabel.removeFromSuperview()
    }
}
```

**Code Update:**

```
import SpriteKit

class ModeScene: SKScene {

    var modeSwitch = UISwitch()
    var motionLabel = UILabel()
    var touchLabel = UILabel()
    var DoneBtn : UIButton!

    override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {

        backgroundColor = SKColor.blackColor()

        modeSwitch.center = CGPoint(x: view.center.x, y: view.frame.size.height / 1.3)
        modeSwitch.addTarget(self, action: Selector("updateMode"), forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.ValueChanged)
        self.view?.addSubview(modeSwitch)

        motionLabel = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 700, height: 200))
        motionLabel.center = CGPoint(x: view.center.x * 3.4, y: view.frame.size.height / 1.3)
        motionLabel.text = "Accelerometer"
        motionLabel.textColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
        motionLabel.font = UIFont(name:"ArialRoundedMTBold", size: 16)
        self.view?.addSubview(motionLabel)

        touchLabel = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 700, height: 200))
        touchLabel.center = CGPoint(x: view.center.x * 2.25, y: view.frame.size.height / 1.3)
        touchLabel.text = "Touch To Move"
        touchLabel.textColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
        touchLabel.font = UIFont(name:"ArialRoundedMTBold", size: 16)
        self.view?.addSubview(touchLabel)

        DoneBtn = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 400, height: 30))
        DoneBtn.center = CGPoint(x: view.center.x * 1.7, y: view.frame.size.height / 14)
        DoneBtn.setTitle("Done", forState: UIControlState.Normal)
        DoneBtn.setTitleColor(UIColor.whiteColor(), forState: UIControlState.Normal)
        DoneBtn.addTarget(self, action: Selector("done"), forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
        self.view?.addSubview(DoneBtn)


        let defaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
        if let motionMode = defaults.objectForKey("motionMode") as? Bool {
            if motionMode {
                // true
                modeSwitch.on = true
            } else {
                // false
                modeSwitch.on = false
            }
        }

        updateMode()

    }


    func updateMode(){
        let defaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
        if modeSwitch.on {
            // mode is accel
            defaults.setBool(true, forKey: "motionMode")
            NSLog("Mode is accel")

        }
        else{
            // mode is touch
            defaults.setBool(true, forKey: "touchMode")
            NSLog("Mode is touch")
        }
    }


    func done(){
        self.scene?.view?.presentScene(StartScene(size: self.scene!.size), transition: SKTransition.fadeWithColor(UIColor.blackColor(), duration: 1))
        headerLabel.removeFromSuperview()
        DoneBtn.removeFromSuperview()
        modeSwitch.removeFromSuperview()
        touchLabel.removeFromSuperview()
        motionLabel.removeFromSuperview()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to actually load the values from `NSUserDefaults`.

You set them with `setValue` and `setObject`, but you never load them back.

Use the `valueForKey` or `objectForKey` methods to retrieve your values.

```
let defaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
let MotionMode = defaults.objectForKey("MotionMode") as! Bool
if MotionMode {
    // true
} else {
    // false
}
```

Even better with safe unwrapping:

```
let defaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
if let MotionMode = defaults.objectForKey("MotionMode") as? Bool {
    if MotionMode {
        // true
    } else {
        // false
    }
}
```

A few notes: variables should begin with a lowercase letter, so "MotionMode" should be "motionMode", etc. You could use the specialized object getters like `boolForKey` instead of the generic `objectForKey` which forces you to typecast to Bool. Of course it goes with `setBool` on the other side. Last: the variable you call "MotionMode" actually holds `NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()`, so I called it "defaults" instead in my example.

*Your question has several parts, but it's better to make a single post for a single question. So I've focused about the failing NSUserDefaults part because it was the most important. Using my answer, if your code still doesn't work because of the UI parts, then you should post a new different question about it to keep things clear.*

Comment: This fixes the switch issue, but still doesn't save the state

Comment: I just saw another error I missed when I answered: you write `modeSwitch.on == false` but it should be `modeSwitch.on = false`. The `==` operator *compares*, the `= ` operator *assigns*. It may be the cause of your `updateMode()` function failure.

Comment: Updated the code after I posted the question and changed this. I updated the original question code. Unfortunately the function calls and works fine - but the state of the button is still not saved.

Comment: You updated the `==` part in the question but there's still the other errors that I addressed in my answer. I hope you're not using the question code to test what I just said in the comments, because indeed it won't work. ;)

Comment: My answer gives only an example with the key "MotionMode" for the Boolean to retrieve. But you're using two different keys for saving, there's also "TouchMode". Maybe you forgot to check this one? I don't see why it couldn't work otherwise if indeed you fixed the other parts.

Comment: I updated the original code with how I updated my function.

Comment: You're mixing up things together. The new updateMode func makes no sense. You're first *retrieving* the MotionMode key, but you don't do anything to the switch, then you check the switch then you save the same key?! Basically it translates to "if it loads as true, and if the button is on, then save it as true" which is probably not what you're trying to achieve. I suggest you read some documentation before working further with this snippet of code. :)

Comment: You're only saving a `true` state for your Bool. You never save a `false` state. So after having saved once (if it does), the value will *always* be true. // Suggestion: instead of using two states and saving both, use one state only. For example, make a *single* "motionModeOn" key and save its value to true or false depending if the switch is on or off. `true` could mean "motion" and `false` could mean "touch". See what I mean?

Comment: Did this and it fixed the issue. Thanks so much.